# Why map() function can't make a new Array?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, gql

I use `react-native` with `graphQL`.

`selectPhoto` is an array containing two strings.

```
Array [
  "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20220223_150530.jpg",
  "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20220223_150453.jpg",
]
```

and I use `map` to make new array with this `array`.

```
  const onValid = async ({ caption }) => {
    const file = selectPhoto.map((sp, index) => {
      console.log(sp, index);
      new ReactNativeFile({
        uri: sp,
        name: `${index}.jpg`,
        type: "image/jpeg",
      });
    });
    console.log(file);
  };
```

when i `console.log`(sp, index) here, each string and index is recorded correctly.

But when I make this `file` then console.log it,

I expect thing like below.

```
Array [
  ReactNativeFile {
    "name": "0.jpg",
    "type": "image/jpeg",
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20220223-011625_KakaoTalk.jpg",
  },
  ReactNativeFile {
    "name": "1.jpg",
    "type": "image/jpeg",
    "uri": "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20220222_161411.jpg",
  },
]
```

**However**, this Array of `undefined` comes.

```
Array [
  undefined,
  undefined,
]
```

Even I tried with `Promise.all` as below.
But still the same as `undefined`.

```
  const onValid = async ({ caption }) => {
    const file = Promise.all(
      selectPhoto.map((sp, index) => {
        console.log(sp, index);
        new ReactNativeFile({
          uri: sp,
          name: `${index}.jpg`,
          type: "image/jpeg",
        });
      })
    );
```

Can you know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why map() function can't make a new Array?

It does make a new Array, but it fills it with `undefined`.

You need a return in there. A function in javascript without a return, will return `undefined`.

```js
selectPhoto.map((sp, index) => {
  console.log(sp, index);

  //here you need to return the ReactNativeFile you just created:
  return new ReactNativeFile({
    uri: sp,
    name: `${index}.jpg`,
    type: "image/jpeg",
  });
});
```

If you wouldn't start a code block (without the {}), then it would work without the `return` keyword:

```js
selectPhoto.map((sp, index) => new ReactNativeFile({
    uri: sp,
    name: `${index}.jpg`,
    type: "image/jpeg",
  })
);
```